# Echo a grep result

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file with

```
dogs:${breed}
```

I want to grep and get ${dog} and get the value, I have exported values as

```
export breed='german'
```

What i have Done is

```
eval "$(grep -iw dogs file_name | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} {print $2}')"
```

which actually results in error as it is taking german as command.
i want the output as follows.

```
german
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `envsubst` to replace shell style variables in literal text:

```
echo 'dogs:${breed}' > file_name
export breed=german
grep -iw dogs file_name | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} {print $2}' | envsubst
```

This outputs `german`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
eval "$(grep -iw dogs file_name | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} {print $2}')"
```

to

```
eval "echo $(grep -iw dogs file_name | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} {print $2}')"
```